# How to insert tags ('>' ;'<')in Javadoc

Tags: javadoc

I want to include tag signs in my documentation.
This is my code and my Javadoc :

```
/**
 *  <Friend>Alone</Friend>
 */
private Item item
```

And this is the javadoc generated :

> Alone

How can I write it in order to have specifically

> `<Friend>Alone</Friend>`

in my javadoc?

Comment: &gt; for '>',  &lt; for '<' and I guess ';' works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside `<pre>` `</pre>` tags with a `@code` block, as below:

```
/**
 *  <pre>
 *    {@code
 *      <Friend>Alone</Friend>
 *    }
 *  </pre>
 */
private Item item
```

Comment: THanks, but { @literal <friend>Alone</Friend>} is working great without the "pre" tags.